# How to get range of dates that are representable/accepted by date(1)/mktime(3)?

Tags: macos, date, posix, libc, bsd

On my modern 64bit Mac, the date 1901-12-14 is the earliest accepted by the following command:

`date -ju -f "%F" "1901-12-14" "+%s"`

I checked the source for the macOS `date` command [here (Apple Open Source)](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-198/date/date.c.auto.html) and it is a failed `mktime` call that gives `date: nonexistent time` error for earlier dates.

I've looked over the source for `mktime` [here (Apple Open Source)](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ntp/ntp-12/ntp/libntp/mktime.c.auto.html) and I think that its a integer representation issue, but I'm not sure.

**How can I find or compute the accepted range of dates of the `date` command (really of `mktime`)?**

And if I wanted to get the Unix time for a date that can't be represented by `mktime` internals, what other libraries or functions can handle earlier dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current macOS (OS X) implementation of `mktime(3)` has a minimum supported Unix time of `INT32_MIN` (`-2147483648`).  This is because [`localtime.c:2102`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1158.50.2/stdtime/FreeBSD/localtime.c.auto.html) assumes the result will fit in a 32-bit integer if the value is less than `INT32_MAX`:

```
/* optimization: see if the value is 31-bit (signed) */
t = (((time_t) 1) << (TYPE_BIT(int) - 1)) - 1;
bits = ((*funcp)(&t, offset, &mytm) == NULL || tmcomp(&mytm, &yourtm) < 0) ? TYPE_BIT(time_t) - 1 : TYPE_BIT(int) - 1;
```

Between *1901-12-14* and *1901-12-13* the Unix time dips below `INT32_MIN`, requires more than 32 bits, and is still less than `INT32_MAX` causing the function run out of `bits`.

This is not much of an issue considering that values before the year 1900 are explicitly disallowed by [`localtime.c:2073`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1158.50.2/stdtime/FreeBSD/localtime.c.auto.html):

```
/* Don't go below 1900 for POLA */
if (yourtm.tm_year < 0)
        return WRONG;
```

(POLA: Principle Of Least Astonishment)

Additionally, `time_t` is not [required to be signed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html).

Comment: from your links, I learned how to get syntax highlighted source listings at that site

`https://opensource.apple.com/source/ntp/ntp-12/ntp/libntp/mktime.c`

becomes

`https://opensource.apple.com/source/ntp/ntp-12/ntp/libntp/mktime.c.auto.html`

thanks